# Не работает функция с изменением переменной

Tags: python, функции, telebot

У меня не работает выведение значения из функции.

```
from misc import is_processing_command, enter_register #во 2 случае
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    global is_processing_command
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    try:
        if (call.data == "TEST"):
            if is_processing_command == False:
                is_processing_command = True
                message = bot.send_message(chat_id, f'*Введите свое имя*', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=back_keyboard())
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, enter_register)
            else:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, f'*Введите свое имя*', parse_mode="Markdown")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Функция `enter_register` находится в другом файле:

```
def enter_register(message):
    try:
        if (message.text == 'Назад'):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы попали в меню', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=keyboard())
            is_processing_command = False
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Заявка на регистрацию отправлена', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=keyboard())
            is_processing_command = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Манипуляции с `is_processing_command` сделаны для предотвращения повторного нажатия кнопки несколько раз.

Если я пишу 1 код, а за ним 2 код, то все превосходно работает, а как только переношу 2 код функции в отдельный файл, то функция в конце не придает значение `False`. Как исправить данную проблему?

Если что, первоначальное значение `is_processing_command` находится в файле с функцией